# Locating the row and col number with the entry number in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the row and column numbers of a matrix once I have the entry number. For example if I am trying to find a 0 in a matrix full of numbers I would try something like this

```
test_array <- array(1,c(30,30))
test_array[200] <- 0
counter <- 0

for(i in test_array){
    counter <- counter + 1
    if(i == 0){
        print(counter)
  }
}
```

`200`

So now I know that at position 200 I have a 0 but how do I check where it is in terms of its row and col.

Something like `(15, 8)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `arr.ind` argument in `which`:

```r
which(test_array == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,]  20   7
```